# Adding lineplot to facetgrid in xarray

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, python-xarray

I have a 2 dimensional time series plotted as FacetGrid via xarray.

```
p = gmt.plot.line(x='time', add_legend=False, alpha = 0.1, color = ('k'), ylim = (-1, 1.2), col='MCrun', col_wrap = 5)
```

[image]
I want to add another lineplot with the same axes and dimensions on top. For individual members that's simply:

```
gmt.isel(MCrun=0).plot.line(x='time', add_legend=False, alpha = 0.1, color = 'k', ylim = (-3, 1.2))
gmt_esmean.isel(MCrun=0).plot.line(x='time', add_legend=False, color = 'red')
```

[image]

But using the same with two facet grids results in 20 plots - 10 with the individual lines and 10 with the mean. The closest I've come is

```
def smean_plot(*args, **kwargs):
    gmt_esmean.plot.line(x='time', add_legend=False, color = 'red')

p = gmt.plot.line(x='time', add_legend=False, alpha = 0.1, color = ('k'), ylim = (-1, 1.2), col='MCrun', col_wrap = 5)
p.map(smean_plot)
```

Which plot all means in all plots and adds unwanted axes titles.
[image]

Any ideas how to only add the mean to the corresponding ensemble are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok one approach I was happy with is to plot the figures one-by-one via subplot in a loop. Set x and y axes as shared and reduce figure margin. It's not as elegant as I would've hoped but works just fine.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=5, nrows=2, figsize=(18,6), sharex=True, sharey=True, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0.2, 'wspace': 0.1})
axs = axs.ravel()
for i in range(10):
        gmt.isel(MCrun=i).plot.line(ax = axs[i], x='time', add_legend=False, alpha = 0.1, color = ('k'), ylim = (-1.2, 0.8))
        gmt_esmean.isel(MCrun=i).plot.line(ax = axs[i], x='time', add_legend=False, color = 'red')+ 1
plt.draw()
```

[image]